# php - automated meta description generation based on another defined variable

Tags: php, meta-tags

On each page of my website, I have a variable I define as the "*description*", and this can be either long or short, and I intend to use it for *meta description* as well.

I was looking around for how I can automatically cut off the extra length in the defined description variable, so it will properly fit in the meta description. I searched and found this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

I can't say I understand enough to develop a solution.

To exemplify what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
$description = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec dapibus leo, vitae euismod eros. Morbi lectus dolor, iaculis id ligula ut, rutrum viverra mauris. Nam ac malesuada velit. Morbi sit amet dui dapibus, ultrices libero fringilla, feugiat lectus.";
?>
```

I have to truncate on the final word of `$description` after 190 characters, and suffix the final word with "...". Like so:

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam nec dapibus leo, vitae euismod eros. Morbi lectus dolor, iaculis id ligula ut, rutrum viverra mauris. Nam ac malesuada velit. Morbi..."
```

And to find the way to write out the echo to produce the above:

```
<?php echo $description(truncated); ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [mb_strimwidth](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strimwidth.php) function. As per the documentation example:

```
<?php echo mb_strimwidth($description, 0, 190, "..."); ?>
```

Comment: Make sure you actually do have the mb extension enabled for this to work. Many hosts (sadly) do not. So you'll be forced to use a combination of wordwrap(), strpos() and substr()

Comment: Oh, fantastic. The thing I was noticing though, that I looked into before deciding to go this route, was tumblr's system for automating the description generation for all users' blogs. It never seems to cut a word in half, and allows leniency for a final word to get through after a certain "soft character limit". This is something I'm trying to figure out along with the regular character limitation.

Answer (score 0):

without mbstring:

```
$truncated = preg_replace('/^(.{190}[^[:punct:]\s]*).*$/', '\\1', $description);
if ( strlen($truncated) < strlen($description) -2 ) {
    // result shouldn't be longer than original
    $truncated .= '...';
}

echo $truncated;
```